# ExtJS package paths are not added to to bootstrap.json

Tags: extjs, bryntum-scheduler

I am using Sencha Cmd to compile my ExtJS project.

I wanted to add a third-party package to my project. For Sencha Cmd to build this, one has to add the package in `app.json`:

```
"requires": [
    "charts",
    "font-awesome",
    "font-ext",
    "bryntum-scheduler",
    "bryntum-scheduler-theme-base",
    "bryntum-scheduler-theme-triton"
],
```

This somehow works, but not completely.

- Cmd builds a production version correctly, so the compiled version is working.
- However, even after multiple runs of `sencha app build production`, the application's `bootstrap.json` does not contain the paths of the package content, and the uncompiled version fails to load because of missing dependencies from that package.

Why is that, where does Sencha Cmd take the contents of `bootstrap.json` file from, and/or how can I see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

you have to run these cammands in your cmd.whenever i change something in bootstrap.json it didnt work at first place.But after running these cammands it works

- sencha app watch
- sencha app refresh